# How to open a new window from hyperlink in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Here is my code

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" class="style1">Click</a>
```

In IE6 when it is been clicked it opens a window but its not a fullsized window its only half of the orginal window size.In IE7 and IE8 its 3/4th.In Mozilla it works good.Without changing the browser settings how can i make my customers to view the landing page in a full new window in IE.Please help me in this context.

regards

Arun

Answer (score 5):

You cannot control the new window's size in pure HTML. You'll have to use either an onclick handler to do a window.open via javascript, passing the new window's size to that function, or more preferrably in your case, use a resize function in the target page to increase the new window to the current screen size.

However, I feel compelled to advise against doing either. It's a non-standard (common, but non-standard) UI experience and can be incredibly frustrating, especially in browsers that open links targeting "_blank" as tabs rather than new windows.

Example of an onclick handler:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="window.open('somepage.html', 'newWindowId', 'width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height); return false;">click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks,

Actually the target page is set in the admin part by the client,so i cant write a resize function in each and every target page.With the default browser settings of IE6,IE7 and IE8  the new tab or new window opening from the link is not a fullsized one.My client said its not fair to force a customer to change the settings.So is there any other way to fix the problem.Thanks for ur time and forthcoming reply

regards 
Arun

Comment: Then an onclick handler would be the only way. I'll update my answer with an example